# Meaning of the bash shortcut Alt+{

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the meaning of the output from the Bash shortcut <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd> (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> on a US keyboard)?

e.g.,

```
$ ls
brown.txt  file1.txt  file2.txt  fox.txt  quick.txt
```

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd> produces the following at the prompt:

```
$ {brown.txt,f{ile{1.txt,2.txt},ox.txt},quick.txt}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a concise representation of the files in current directory. `bash` will expand it to the same as output of `ls`.
Example - `file{a,b}.txt` gets expanded to `filea.txt fileb.txt` in `bash`. So, something like `cp file{a,b}.txt` gets expanded to `cp filea.txt fileb.txt`, which will copy filea.txt to fileb.txt.